# Error: Model does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have the following error, I think I have to ask a builder my question is how do I do it?

Error:

> 'CascadingModelGastos' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

```
@model List<INCASICS.Models.CascadingModelGastos>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "OMA";
  INCASICS.Models.CascadingModelGastos grid = new INCASICS.Models.CascadingModelGastos(Model, rowsPerPage: 10);
}
```

Model:

```
public class CascadingModelGastos 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public CascadingModelGastos()
    {
        this.Proyecto = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.Recurso = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.SubRecurso = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    [Display(Name = "Selecciona Proyecto")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Requerido")]
    public List<SelectListItem> Proyecto { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Selecciona Recurso")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Requerido")]
    public List<SelectListItem> Recurso { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Selecciona Sub Recurso")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Requerido")]
    public List<SelectListItem> SubRecurso { get; set; }

    public int ProyectoID { get; set; }
    public int RecursoID { get; set; }
    public int SubRecursoID { get; set; }

    public string Nombre_Proyecto { get; set; }

}
```

I'm a little new for this and that's why I support myself here to see if you can help me resolve this question.

Comment: You don't have a constructor defined that takes two arguments and the class you've posted doesn't even have a `Model` or `RowsPerPage` properties?

Comment: if I have them defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you are creating instance of CascadingModelGastos (`INCASICS.Models.CascadingModelGastos grid = new INCASICS.Models.CascadingModelGastos(Model, rowsPerPage: 10);`) with two parameters and there is no constructor in the class that takes two parameters.

Please modify your CascadingModelGastos to contain second constructor that takes two parameters as below:

```
public class CascadingModelGastos 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public CascadingModelGastos()
    {
        this.Proyecto = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.Recurso = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.SubRecurso = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    public CascadingModelGastos(List<INCASICS.Models.CascadingModelGastos> lst, int rowsPerPage)
    {
        this.Proyecto = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.Recurso = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.SubRecurso = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    [Display(Name = "Selecciona Proyecto")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Requerido")]
    public List<SelectListItem> Proyecto { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Selecciona Recurso")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Requerido")]
    public List<SelectListItem> Recurso { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Selecciona Sub Recurso")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Requerido")]
    public List<SelectListItem> SubRecurso { get; set; }

    public int ProyectoID { get; set; }
    public int RecursoID { get; set; }
    public int SubRecursoID { get; set; }

    public string Nombre_Proyecto { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Ok, it was solved, one more question, I have this full `@Html.DropDownListFor (Model => Model.ProyectoID, Model.Proyecto, "Select")`.......But the following error comes up: 
**Does not contain definition for "ProyectoID"**

Comment: Your view's model is collection of CascadingModelGastos (as defined on the top of view `@model List<INCASICS.Models.CascadingModelGastos>`) but Proyecto is property/member of CascadingModelGastos. So, you need to use it in for loop. Do you have for loop (or foreach loop - some kind of looping mechanism) in your view?

Comment: ok what I try to do is fill a `tableStyle` that filled with the aforementioned, and also the`@ Html.DropDownListFor` but I get the errors I mentioned ..... Looking at the Wen I found it would be a better way with `@model Tuple <...>` so I define my two models ... Is this correct?

Comment: could you post your complete view with the error you are getting.